# Open Word document with cursor disabled

Tags: ms-word, cursor, readonly

Is there any way to create a word document where the cursor is invisible or disabled? After I save the document as read only, I want it to be opened like a pdf where even if a cursor is placed and typed, nothing is written on the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Options > "Security" Tab

Select "Protect Document..." and follow the prompts.  You can restrict the document down to completely read only.

Comment: The cursor still shows but I got what I wanted. Thank you James.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Word 2007 you can use **[this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F1FC413C-6D89-4F15-991B-63B07BA5F2E5&displaylang=en)** plug-in to actually save it as a PDF.